# How can I change the line colors when plotting with ggcompetingrisks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

I created a plot using ggcompetingrisks that is illegible. I would like to color code the time periods and differentiate the risk groups by using dashed vs dotted lines. Right now it's flipped.

```
p3 <- ggcompetingrisks(fit = TimePer_fit, 
                       multiple_panels = F, 
                       ggtheme = theme_minimal(),
                       coef = 1.96, #95% CI
                       conf.int = F,
                       xlim = c(0, 45),
                       ylim = c(0, 0.5),
                       xlab = "Days", 
                       ylab = "Probability",
                       title = "Cumulative Incidence by Time Period") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), #center title
          axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)), #pad y axis label
          axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 10, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0))) + #pad x axis label
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("risk 1", "risk 2"),  
                        values = c("#F8766D", "619CFF"), 
                        name = element_blank()) +  # do not name legend
    scale_linetype_manual(labels = c("Period 1","Period 2","Period 3","Period 4", "Period 5"),
                          values = c("solid", "longdash", "dashed","twodash", "dotted"),
                          name = element_blank())
```

[image: Cumulative Incidence Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can look into the plot object and see that `colour` is automatically mapped to `event` and `linetype` is mapped to `group`. These are not easily swapped using normal methods, as they are in the `quosure` form. (The quosure: a data structure that captures an expression along with its associated environment, as found in function arguments. -Hadley). But we can use other methods.

Here is a dummy example from the `survminer` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cmprsk)
library(survminer)

set.seed(2)
ss <- rexp(100)
gg <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('BRCA','LUNG','OV'))
cc <- factor(sample(0:2,100,replace=TRUE),0:2,c('no event', 'death', 'progression'))
strt <- sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)

# handles cuminc objects
print(fit <- cmprsk::cuminc(ss,cc,gg,strt))
g<-ggcompetingrisks(fit,
                    multiple_panels = F)

g
```

[image: Plot 1]

We can see event is mapped to colour, and group to linetype.

```
g$mapping$colour <quosure> expr: ^event env:  0x00000295351a3b58

g$mapping$linetype <quosure> expr: ^group env:  0x00000295351a3b58
```

Now we access those elements in the plot object and swap them over.

```
library(rlang)

g$mapping$colour<-quo_set_expr(g$mapping$colour, quote(group))
g$mapping$linetype<-quo_set_expr(g$mapping$linetype, quote(event))

g
```

[image: Plot 2]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this for so long!

Comment: Am I able to do something analogous for the fill color for the confidence intervals? I tried doing this g$mapping$fill<-quo_set_expr(g$mapping$fill, quote(group)) but got this error: Error: 'format_error' is not an exported object from 'namespace:cli'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you could try is to choose two contrasting colors. Also you can use this function `facet_wrap(. ~ x)`, using as parameter either risk or period, and in this way you can have a clean plot.